# Adding Data in 1 tables through trigger on multiple tables

Tags: oracle, plsql, database-trigger

How do I add data in a table which contains attributes of two different tables which are not linked together?

Table 1 has col1,col2,col3  (assume all are numbers)
Table 2 has col4,col5,col6  (assume all are numbers)
Table 3 has A,B,C,D,E,F (assume all are numbers)

Question is that if any insertion occurs on table 1 and table 2, their data should be loaded in table 3.

I used the normal approach
of

```
create or replace trigger trig_name
before insert on table1,table2 --> not allowed
for each row
begin
if inserting then
insert into table3 values (:new.col1,:new.col2,:new.col3,:new.col4,:new.col5,:new.col6)
end if;
end;
/
```

So if I have to make two different triggers for table 1 and table 2, wouldn't that create two rows of data leaving some columns null?

Comment: Why does table 3 exist at all? Sounds to me like it should be replaced with a view that selects from tables 1 and 2.

Comment: You say `table1` and `table2` aren't linked together.  But `table3` is supposed to link them together.  So there must be some way that you can determine which row in `table1` maps to which row in `table2`.  When you insert data, you are, presumably, inserting into one table at a time.  If you insert into `table1` and then insert into `table2`, how do you know that the two inserts are related?

Comment: would create one row in table3 for each insertion into either table (1/2)  leaving some colums null.

Comment: If table 1 and table 2 don't have a (key) column in common it is **impossible** to create coherent rows in table 3. So either the data model is broken or the requirement is nonsense. (It is possible to fill up table 3 with randomly joined rows from 1 and 2 - please edit your question to say whether that is what you want.)

Comment: the question was in my exam, of ADBMS and at that time i was also confused because there was nothing to link them together and i was scratching my head in exam that if i am to create two triggers there will be two rows in table3.

Comment: What do you understand by the term ADBMS? Oracle is an RDBMS not [an accumulative event-driven data-store](https://www.techopedia.com/definition/17438/active-database-management-system-adbms) (although undoubtedly one could wrangle events in it).

Answer (score 0):

Although creating a view as suggested by @EdStevens is (IMO) a superior answer, what you want can be done. And yes it requires 2 triggers. In Oracle, and all other DBMS that I'm aware of, a trigger can only fire on 1 table.  
However, they can be reduced somewhat. There is no need for the "if inserting" test. The trigger is declared as "on insert" therefore the test will always be true.  The actual issue it you cannot refer  columns from table2 in the table1 trigger and likewise the other way around. What you need is to name the columns you are inserting, **actually always a better approach**. So:

```
create or replace trigger table1_bir
   before insert on table1 
   for each row
begin
     insert into table3(col1, col2, col3)
     values (:new.col1,:new.col2,:new.col3);
end;
/

create or replace trigger table2_bir
   before insert on table2 
   for each row
begin
     insert into table3(col4, col5, col6)
     values (:new.col4,:new.col5,:new.col6);
end;
/
```

Comment: this will create create two sets of rows, i'll share the exact question in some time when i get to recheck my exam.